# Program to find factors of number using for loops

Tags: java

My teacher has assigned us a mini project of making a program that will find all factors of any user inputted number. I am using a for loop to do so, but the for loop is failing and I can't figure out why.

Here is the relevant code:

```
System.out.println("Type a number");
Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

for (double number = 1; num.nextDouble() % number == 0; number++) {
    if (num.nextDouble() % number != 0)
        continue;

    if (number > num.nextDouble()) 
        break;

    System.out.println(number + "is a factor of " + num);
}
```

I have looked on Stack Overflow to see if there is a relevant question for my problem, and from what I could find it hasn't been brought up before. If someone could point out what I assume to be a logic error, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What's happening to cause the loop to 'fail'?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: When I run the program, the I have been testing it by inputting 4, and the loop runs, but when it should print 1.0 and 2.0, it only prints 1.0. I assume it's a logic error I just can't find it. Sorry for not specifying before

Comment: The formatting of your code suggests to me that you’re missing some braces after your if statements - I’ve edited your post to more clearly display the behaviour of your code

Comment: I know that, I found you only need braces on an if statement if there is more than one affect for the statement, otherwise you only need a semicolon

Comment: if I get you right, the problem is that you're exiting the loop when the remainder is 0. you probably meant to do it when number is bigger than user input @PhoenixTrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to compare user input to a variable, however you're getting the user input in the declaration of the for loop, hence it waits for `nextDouble` everytime the loop is executed since it will check if `num.nextDouble() % number == 0` is `true` every loop.

Your code appears `'stuck'` but really it's just waiting for you to enter another number.

### Implementation in your code

In the example below I put the `nextDouble` before the for loop so it will only wait for input from the user once.

```
double userInput = num.nextDouble();
for (double number = 1; userInput % number == 0; number++) {

}
```

You're doing this a couple times in your code, this is a full example using your code:

```
System.out.println("Type a number");
Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
double userInput = num.nextDouble();
for (double number = 1; userInput % number == 0; number++) {
    if (userInput % number != 0) {
        continue;
    }

    if (number > userInput) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(number + "is a factor of " + userInput);
}
```

### An alternative

However since you don't actually seem to be doing anything with a `double` & since your for loop can be way simpler this will also do the job:

```
int userInput = num.nextInt();

for (int number = 1; number < userInput; number++) {
    if (userInput % number == 0) {
        System.out.println(number + " is a factor of " + userInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the comments on their question, OP specified that their problem isn't that (they seem to be fine with it for whatever reason)

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to have fixed another problem but not the main problem

Comment: @TilmanB.akaNerdyyy No, this is exactly OPs problem, he says that it's only printing `1.0` once, which is due to the fact that it's trying to validate the expression in the for loop and therefore executing `nextDouble` again.

Comment: It should be printing 1.0 and 2.0, but the for loop is running only once so 1.0 is all that comes out

Comment: @PhoenixTrite Check the answer again I've updated it.

Comment: his program still wouldn't behave as expected because it only runs as long as the remainder of that divison is 0 (which is bad on it's own because of double precision, but that's not even my point). so if, for example, you were to input `15.0` into that (only once in your version), it would only print `1.0` instead of the expected `1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 15.0`. it is unable to "skip" numbers because it exits on the first one that isn't a factor

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your code include, but are not necessarily limited to:

- It reads input and generally handles numbers as `double`s.  It doesn't make much sense to talk about factors of non-integers.  Instead use `Scanner.nextInt()` or `Scanner.nextLong()`, and handle all your numbers via the corresponding integer data type.
- It reads a *new* number from the input every time it wants to examine the number whose factors are being determined.  Instead, read the input *once*, before the loop or in its initialization clause.  Store that result in a variable, and access it from there.
- The loop condition is unsuitable. It terminates the loop if `number` exactly divides the input number (subject to the numeric precision of type `double`), without printing anything.  Instead, loop until `number` exceeds an appropriate threshold (e.g. the value of the input number).
- At the end, it prints the string value of the `Scanner` where it means to print the value of the number that was factored.  Instead, print the variable established for holding the number.